# ListProperty item by index in kv

Tags: kivy

I have stored highscores in a ListProperty() and I'm trying to fetch an item from that list by index inside kv file (code below). **It keeps saying "list index out of range".**

.py file:

```
scores = ListProperty()
```

.kv file:

```
Label:
    text: str(root.scores[1])
```

If I remove the [1] index part and just have str(root.scores) it perfectly shows the entire list.

Answer (score 1):

I just found an answer I think. When greating a new ListProperty() I have to know how big the list is in order to be able to access the items in kv using list indexed.
So when I created the ListPropert as:

```
scores = ListProperty([['', 0], ['', 0], ['', 0], ['', 0]])
```

Then it worked perfectly in kv file.

I assume this goes with all the kivy properties, so that you have to know exact size of the property prehand.

Comment: You don't have to know the exact size of the property, just be aware that your kv rules may be applied with the default value you set.